# Is there anyway to host a bot dashboard for free?

Tags: python, web, discord.py

I am working with discord.py, I am wondering if there is a way I can get python to change the data and read the data off a website, like the [MEE6](https://mee6.xyz/) dashboard.

I have data user data like level and XP stored in a [postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/) database, hosted with [elephantsql](http://elephantsql.com)
I have the bot hosted on [heroku](http://heroku.com).

Is there a way to acomplish this with a
[WIX](https://www.wix.com/) site or a [google site](https://sites.google.com/new)?

Edit:
So ^ wont work but are there any good tutorials out there on how to use
[HelioHost](https://www.heliohost.org/) or [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [netlify](https://www.netlify.com/) to host a website which can be controlled through private GitHub repositories. A dashboard consists of the backend to edit a database so even [helios host](https://www.heliohost.org/) will work. You cannot use Wix or a google site as they only support front end code.

Answer (score 2):

For hosting the bot you could use [heroku](https://heroku.com) and every time you change something you could push it like using a git repository.

or you can use serverless With [Google cloud functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions)

To make a discord.py bot run 24/7 but still be able to edit it

You can use cogs, which will allow you to load, unload, and reload extensions. So then all you need to do is make changes in this cog, and then reload it, for the changes to take place.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?#cogs

Comment: This is more or less what I am doing, I use heroku to host my bot, I have cogs like xp, admin, fun. What I am wondering is how do I have a _(free)_ website that the user of the bot can access and use to change the way to bot interacts with his/her server. This would also include viewing the level/xp of each user in the server.

Comment: Hi @MakerBen you can go ahead and create your website If the website is static you can host that on Github Pages or if your website includes somebacked login you can host the website separately on heroku. I think there is no way to host on Wix or other CMS if you want to show CP